# String search in all .dll files in project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rider

I am inspecting a large C# project. I tend to use `Shift+Ctrl+F` a lot to find in which files a specific function or field name occurs.

The problem is that `Shift+Ctrl+F` does not search inside .dll files that are included inside the project. Once you decompile a class from .dll file, you can search within with `Ctrl+F`, but I found no way to also search among other files.

How can I search all files (.dll or .cs) for a string? I am using Rider IDE, but can also revert to Visual Studio.

Comment: You can use the Object Browser window to search within class names and method signatures in referenced libraries etc. That won't search inside the actual code in the the library though.

Comment: You can use ILSpy to search within compiled DLLs.

Comment: Just tried ILSpy.. string search Shift+Ctrl+F misses a ton of results.

Comment: Then you're using it wrong, but I can't say how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open dll with JetBrains DotPeek, generate csproj and then search for text inside.

I had a similar problem. Vote this issue please https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-21268

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ allows search in files with any extensions, including *.dll.
Always have it installed specifically for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Ctrl+Shift+K` for search assemblies

Answer (score 0):

There might be an easier way but you can always **export the assembly as a project using [JetBrains dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) (or other decompiler) and then search within the project** like you would normally do in your IDE.

1. **Launch [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)**
2. **Open your assembly** in dotPeek

[image]

3. **Right-click your assembly file** in Assembly Explorer menu pane and **select `Export to Project`**

[image]

4. **Open** the newly exported project in your IDE and **search solution-wide** (Navigate -> Search Everywhere in JetBrains Rider is great for this but you can use whatever solution-wide search functionality your IDE has)